# Cassandra is forcing to open CQL native port on ipv6 interface

Tags: cassandra-2.0

I'm trying to connect to one of nodes of running instance of Cassandra servers. Nodetool shows that they synchronized well.

```
[root@cassandra1 ~]# /opt/dsc-cassandra-2.1.8/bin/nodetool status
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load       Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                              Rack
UN  10.0.17.20  100.4 KB   256     100.0%              rack1
UN  10.0.17.24  249.39 KB  256     100.0%              rack1
```

When I run `netstst -tulnap` I can see following settings

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:44907             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4428/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      756/sshd
tcp        0      0 10.0.17.20:7000             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4428/java
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      842/master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7199              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4428/java
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:199               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      744/snmpd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9160              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4428/java
tcp        0      0 10.0.17.20:7000             10.0.17.24:46314            ESTABLISHED 4428/java
tcp        0      0 10.0.17.20:43083            10.0.17.24:7000             ESTABLISHED 4428/java
tcp        0      0 10.0.17.20:22               10.0.17.50:53665            ESTABLISHED 4662/sshd
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:9042       :::*                        LISTEN      4428/java
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      756/sshd
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:34705      ::ffff:127.0.0.1:44907      TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:43039      ::ffff:127.0.0.1:7199       TIME_WAIT   -
```

What tells that 7199 port used to syncing between nodes works in ipv4, ssh on ipv4/6 and the port I'm insterested in is only listening on ipv6 interface.

To enforce using ipv4, even when it is not nesecary I set flag `listen_interface_prefer_ipf6: false`

```
listen_address: 10.0.17.20
listen_interface_prefer_ipv6: false
org.apache.cassandra.auth.AllowAllInternodeAuthenticator
start_native_transport: true
native_transport_port: 9042
```

I don't know how to force Cassandra service to open 9042 port on ipv4.

Comment: Whats your rpc_address in cassandra.yaml listed as? Just 127.0.0.1?

Comment: rpc_address I have set to `localhost`

Comment: Then I set rpc_address to real IP on both servers. They still see each other, but still open 9042 only in ipv6 interface.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you manage to find how to force IPv4?

Comment: I am also facing same issue how you solved it?

Comment: I did not put any answer to this question as the issue solved itself or by some my manipulation which was hard for me to define. My impression was that starting ipv4 takes more time and it was working even when it was not enlisted properly all the time. For now it is hard to tell the details, because I don't even remember which server it was.